# Clearing the "cache" of computed properties upon each reload

Tags: vue.js, array.prototype.map

I have this code:

TEMPLATE:

```
<b-dropdown class="dropdown-small dropdown-channel" text="Axes">
        <b-dropdown-item v-for="(item, index) in chartAxes" :key="index" @click="displayAxis(item)">
          {{ item }}
        </b-dropdown-item>
      </b-dropdown>
```

COMPUTED:

```
chartAxes(): string[]  {
        const axes = this.chart?.axes?.items
            ?.filter((axis: Tee.IAxis) => axis.title.text != "")
            ?.map((axis: Tee.IAxis) => axis.title.text)
               if (axes === undefined) {
              return [];
          } 
          return axes;
      },
```

What this does is show the different lines in a graph in a dropdown (and one can choose a specific line to populate the left-hand axis with).

The issue I am facing is every time I load a new graph, the available lines are just accumulated in the dropdown. What I want to do is to clear it and re-populate it with the new lines. Tried to push this into an array and then clear that, but doesn’t work.

Comment: Can u show the code how u assign the value of this.chart?

Comment: Maybe instead of computed you should call a method and clear old lines first

Comment: @HongJian - There are graphs (with multiple lines) for hundreds of sensors so quite a long code to post here I think

Comment: @DavidGo - could you show an example of how you would refactor that into a method? 'casue when I try to just put it in the method object, the dropdown is empty...